# setting background image for a Jquery Mobile button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have to set a background image for the jquery mobile button.e.g button with "page flip " image in the background. But that button/image will have some text on it and this text will be dynamic in nature. if i use  as a button then i am unable to write any text on it because it is an image.

My requirement is to have a page flip image as a button with some text on it like it will display monthly acct balance on it but when click can show the detail in the next page.

i tried setting it as background but image is not appearing in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to CSS etc. But after some search i have found following article of superimposing text over image. It might be useful for some people who are new inn CSS like me.
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/superimpose-text-over-an-image-by-using-css-styled-text/5169871.

the above technique worked for me. So accepted this as answer, in case others wants to try the same technique.